# Basic IVR Setup in vicidial

Tags: asterisk, ivr

I'm completely new to this. Can you please assist me on this below?

Once the customer call to our Toll free number >> PRI number >> After that how the number detects the exact IVR setup in the extensions.conf.. I've already setup a normal campaign.

Do we need to setup a separate IVR campaign to route the number or do we have any other options ??

Thank You.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that in your asterisk configuration files, that your PRI is sending inbound calls into the "trunkinbound" context. Then you can configure it all within the VICIdial web administration screens. First, you need to create a Call menu, then point a DID to it(both of these are in the "Inbound" section of the web administration). I would also suggest for more in-depth tutorials on how to do this, getting the Manager Manual from vicidial.org.